# Can the complexitiy be reduced from O(n^2) to O(n) when comparing two large sets of data?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have a large set of items(~2 million) in which I need to compare each item to every other item in this set.

Each item itself is a set of strings that are concatenated to a single string. So string `a` will then be compared to all other strings `b` using difflib.

In the long run I want to switch to a different library than difflib but even a 100x speedup would not be fast enough. The items are not stored in a database, but directly in memory. I'm using two for-loops which is obviously not a satisfying solution.

The code looks something like this:

```
for a in data:
    for b in data:
        # calculate similarity of a and b
```

Is there any better method to compare all items separately?

Comment: What kind of data? What kind of comparison?

Comment: "I need to compare each item to every other item" Then your goal is inherently O(n^2),there is nothing an algorithm can do about it.

Comment: If the comparisons are independent, you can parallelize the code, but that will only give you a constant factor speed up. Going from O(n^2) to O(n) is not possible, since your *output* consists of O(n^2) different values.

Comment: This question won't be answerable unless you give specific details about how the strings need to be compared, and what you need the results of the comparisons for.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming both `a` and `b` are the same length we can just iterate over the length of them:

```
#if length not equal then items not equal and we can save time.
if len(a) != len(b):
   return False 

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != b[i]:
        return False

return True
```

EDIT:

I misread hence my original answer is invalid.

You can improve your runtime by creating 2 buckets for each item, one for similar items, and one for different items.

By doing so before any comparison you can add two checks, is `a` similar to items similar to `b` or is similar to items different from `b`

Assuming the length of `a` and `b` is long enough, and that they are enough similar items (if all items are different then theres no point of this approach) in the database then this should improve performance.

Simple PUESDO sample:

```
similar_buckets = {}
different_buckets = {}

def func():
    for string in data:
        if string not in similar_buckets:
            similar_buckets[string] = set()
        if string not in different_buckets:
            different_buckets[string] = set()

        for string2 in data:
            # these occur in O(1)
            if string2 in similar_buckets[string]:
                continue #true
            elif string2 in different_buckets[string]:
                continue #false

            #expensive
            if string == string2:
                similar_buckets[string].add(string2)
                different_buckets[string2] = similar_buckets[string]
                continue
            else:
                different_buckets[string].add(string2)
                similar_buckets[string2] = different_buckets[string]
                continue

func()
```

Mind you this is still O(n^2), but we have the possibility to boost actual performance by a large margin.

Comment: The OP explicitly said that every item had to be compared to every other item, not just corresponding pairs

Comment: I think you're still misreading it. The OP isn't looking to cluster items, but compute all-pairs similarity scores. (Maybe that's just the first step towards clustering, though; it's unclear.)